# Future with RateLimiter

Tags: scala, concurrency, future, rate-limiting

Suppose I've got a simple blocking HTTP client like this:

```
def httpGet(url: URL): Future[String] = ???
```

Now I want to use `httpGet` to call a server with a request rate limit; e.g. 1000 requests/sec. Since the standard library does not provide a rate limiter I will use [RateLimiter](https://github.com/google/guava/blob/master/guava/src/com/google/common/util/concurrent/RateLimiter.java) of [Guava](https://guava.dev/):

```
import com.google.common.util.concurrent.RateLimiter
import scala.concurrent.{ExecutionContext, Future, blocking}

def throttled[A](fut: => Future[A], rateLimiter: RateLimiter)
                (implicit ec: ExecutionContext): Future[A] = {
  Future(blocking(rateLimiter.acquire())).flatMap(_ => fut)
}

implicit val ec = ExecutionContext.global
val rateLimiter = RateLimiter.create(permitsPerSeconds = 1000.0)
val throttledFuture = throttled(httpGet(url), rateLimiter)
```

Does it make sense ?
Would you use another execution context to execute `rateLimiter.acquire()` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you're using `blocking` around the `acquire`, it's okay, IMO.

Depending on how much work gets done in the thread which calls `httpGet`, if you're on Scala 2.13 it might be worth considering using the `parasitic` execution context.

Style nit, but it might be worth taking advantage of Scala's ability to use `{`'s around single argument lists:

```
def throttled[A](rateLimiter: RateLimiter)(fut: => Future[A])(implicit ec: ExecutionContext): Future[A]

val throttledFuture = throttled(rateLimiter) { httpGet(url) }
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I am on 2.12 so I cannot use `parasitic`.  Like the style remark: I will use it.